# Apollo Client requests data components to be mounted twice in React using useQuery

Tags: reactjs, apollo-client

I am having some trouble with Apollo Client and wonder how `useQuery`  requests data

```js
import { useQuery, gql } from "@apollo/client";
import RecentPosts from "../components/home/RecentPosts";
const Home = () => {

  const GET_RECENT_POSTS = gql`
    query getRecnetPost {
      recentPost {
        id
        author
        title
      }
    }
  `;
  const { data } = useQuery(GET_RECENT_POSTS);

  console.log(data)

  return (
    <main className="w-full m-auto lg:w-[70vw]">
      {data && <RecentPosts name="rencentPosts" posts={data.recentPost} />}
    </main>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

`console.log(data)` is printed twice, once as `undefined`, and again as the data we need, not the environment